# Can you connect Active Directory to SharePoint via JavaScript/ SPServices/ or SOAP?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, jquery

I am trying to connect a AD to a SharePoint 2013 list form so that the SharePoint form is filled in automatically with data from the Active Directory (i.e. contact information). Is this possible?

I have currently found the partial solutions below, but do not know how to apply them. Please advise.

one:

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetUserInfo",
async: false,
userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
        curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
        curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
        curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID")+";#"+$(this).attr("Name");
    });
}
});
```

This little function will create three vars:

```
curUserId = the current users ID (Ex: 1)
curUserName = the current users Name (Ex: DOMAIN\user)
curFullUserName = the ID and Name combined in SP format (Ex: 1;#DOMAIN\user)
```

Two:

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetUserColleagues", 
AccountName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Name"}), 
completefunc:function(data,status) {
    //process GetUserColleaguesResult... 
}
});
```

How would I use either of the solutions, if i need to get the  title(name), Product, and review group to be automaticly filled in when creating a new item form in the a list? Could someone please help me with the code.

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetUserInfo",
async: false,
userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
        curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
        curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
        curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID")+";#"+$(this).attr("Name");
    });
}
});
```

How would I use the other information from the AD? i.e product, and then how would i connect the requester name (maybe via username?)?

Comment: Depending on which parts you want to pull out, it's entirely possible. I've seen it done, but don't know exactly how to do it myself.

Comment: That would depend entirely on the conventions in place. You can use SOAP Requests to get data from the user profile service, which is generally populated from Active Directory.

Comment: How would i do this using SOAP?